# Почему код успешно компилируется?

Tags: c++, ооп, дружественная-функция

Я создал три класса, в каждом по приватному атрибуту, и с помощью дружественной функции использовал их значения. Но функция дружественна лишь к одному классу и должна уметь работать только с одним элементом, и выдавать ошибку невозможности доступа к атрибутам других классов?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class hom {
private:
    int ppp = 2;
    friend void aat(hom& obj);
};
class hliw {

private:
    int zalu = 3;
    friend void aat(hom& obj);
};

class tov {

private:
    int za = 3;
    friend void aat(hom& obj);
};

hliw w;
hom q;

tov r;
void aat(hom& obj) {
    int result = q.ppp + w.zalu+r.za;
    cout << result;

}
int main() {
    aat(q);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваша функция объявлена как дружественная в трех классах, поэтому она может обращаться к закрытым полям всех трех классов, в которых вы объявили ее другом.

Что она и делает :)

Попробуйте удалить строку

```
friend void aat(hom& obj);
```

из одного из классов и посмотрите на результат - функция больше не сможет обратиться к закрытому полу этого класса.

И, кстати, код и не должен "крашиться", он должен перестать компилироваться.